# Multivariable Calculus, Double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$
Evaluate \iint_{R}^{ } xy^2
$

where R is the finite region in the first quadrant bounded by $x=y^2$ and  $y=x^2$.

Answer given is $\frac{3}{56}$

I cannot seem to get this right. I thought that the bounds of both integrals should be 0 to 1 to fulfill both regional bounds of R. As in: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}xy^2 dxdy$. But this gives me a false answer of $\frac{1}{6}$. How should I be reasoning about the bounds of the integrals?

Thank you in advance,
Raoul

Comment: Draw a picture of the region. Think of it as a union of vertical line segments (integrating with respect to $y$ first), or as a union of horizontal line segments (integrating with respect to $x$ first). The bounds of the inner integral correspond to the endpoints of the line segments. The bounds of the outer integral correspond to the interval over which the different line segments span.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, ~~0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1, ~x^2 \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{x}\}$$

so

$$\iint_{R} x y^2 \,dxdy = \int_{x=0}^1 \left( \int_{y=x^2}^{\sqrt{x}} xy^2 \,dy\right) \,dx = \int_{x=0}^1 \left( x \left[{y^3 \over 3 }\right]_{y=x^2}^{y=\sqrt{x}}\right) \,dx$$

$$\iint_{R} x y^2 \,dxdy = {1 \over 3}\int_{x=0}^1 \left( x^{5/2} - x^7 \right) \,dx = {1 \over 3} \left[{2 \over 7} x^{7/2} - {1 \over 8} x^8\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}$$
$$\iint_{R} x y^2 \,dxdy = {1 \over 3} \left({2 \over 7} - {1 \over 8} \right) = {1 \over 3} \times {9 \over 56} = {3 \over 56}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!
The first explanation of R makes it very understandable!
I'd upvote you if I could!

Comment: Sure. You can accept the answer if it suits you. But there is no rush, someone else might also give an answer.